# Unable to deploy new version in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a new version to a elastic beanstalk environment, but it is giving me this error. The same version I had deployed weeks ago, and was working fine.

Here is a screenshot 
[Updating Auto Scaling group named: *** failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj3OR.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, you have Mentioned wrong **Db-instance name** or Template is not able to get the DB Instance which you have specified.

while Setting up Auto-scaling it's getting failed. It will be good if you can provide the Template for better understanding of error.

Comment: What exactly is a Template ? Where do I find it? This problem has started since this morning. It was working perfectly before. Please help.

Comment: The Code which you are deploying to Beanstalk.

Comment: The code I am trying to deploy is a sample code with a slight modification to print hello world.

Comment: So their is error in that code. plz check with the (auto-scaling or where so ever you have mentioned DBInstance) files in the .ebextension folder

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/php-v1.zip is the link to the code I am trying to deploy

Comment: can you please go to AWS cloudformation and see where your stack has failed